# How to set value/term of a Woocommerce attribute text field in admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin which is supposed to auto-fill the attributes text field.

There is a URL text field where user enters URL, on focus out I trigger a AJAX call through which I am able to save the data but I am looking to accomplish here is to show the saved data on highlighted fields as well.

[image]

I am using following code in a hook to display:

```
if( function_exists( 'wc_get_attribute_taxonomies' ) && ( $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() ) ) {

    $defaults = array();
    $name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name );
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $key=>$tax ) {
                $defaults[ $name ] = array (
                    'name' => $name,
                    'value' => 'thisTextShouldAppearInHighlightedFieldsOfScreenShot',
                    'position' => $key+1,
                    'is_visible' => 1,
                    'is_variation' => 1,
                    'is_taxonomy' => 1,
                );

            update_post_meta( $post->ID , '_product_attributes', $defaults );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!